# Riddle about small things

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Hopefully this one will occupy you longer.

```
I am a ghost
discarnate and sneaky.
Invisible at most.
Catching me is tricky.

I am an awkward loner
team work is not my thing at all.
To cooperate with my persona
you need huge meeting hall.

I am very fair
and never pick a side.
You know me, I am everywhere.
But who am I?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a

> Neutrino

I am a ghost
discarnate and sneaky.
Invisible at most.
Catching me is tricky.

> Neutrinos are hard to catch and not visible to the human eye.

I am an awkward loner
team work is not my thing at all.

> Neutrinos do not interact with each other, nor with most other particles.

To cooperate with my persona
you need huge meeting hall.

> The huge meeting hall is a [neutrino detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_detector).

I am very fair
and never pick a side.

> <strike>Since they don't collide with other particles, neutrinos don't change direction.</strike> **Update after OP's clarification:** not picking a side is about being neutral (having no positive or negative charge).

You know me, I am everywhere.

> True :-)

Comment: Hi GOTO :) Could it refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_%28physics%29 (the picking a side thing?)

Comment: @d'alar'cop That could surely be... how would you explain that?

Comment: Not really sure... maybe "they don't chose a side" because the spin of an atom isn't know until it's observed or something? (Quantum Mechanics - I'm not expert :p)

Comment: @d'alar'cop Me neither :) If my interpretation is correct, maybe the OP can provide some feedback...

Comment: not picking a side is about being neutral :) no positive or negative charge

Comment: all other clues have correct interpretation => solved :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it can be

> Argon (Air gas)

Because:

***I am a ghost
discarnate and sneaky.
Invisible at most.
Catching me is tricky.***

> You can't obviously see it, and you can't catch it easily

***I am an awkward loner
team work is not my thing at all.
To cooperate with my persona
you need huge meeting hall.***

> Since it is about 1% of total air, you need a lot of air in order to have a significantly high concentration of Argon (that's why I think you need a huge meeting hall, because it has lot of air in it). Teamwork is not its thing because its name derives from the Greek word "lazy"

***I am very fair
and never pick a side.
You know me, I am everywhere.
But who am I?***

> It is inert, so it doesn't react to anything. It's everywhere because it is in air.

Comment: what about the "huge meeting hall"...? nice answer btw

Comment: You are very close in your interpretation, indeed. But  what about the huge meeting hall? :) And is Argon really everywhere?

Comment: "To cooperate with my persona" (In order to work with it) "you need huge meeting hall." (A huge meeting hall contains a lot of air, so (relatively) a lot of argon)

@zlobi: On average, I think yes. Well, not where vacuum is :P

Comment: @AndreaGottardi Not bad, but it might be a bit too much of a stretch :p

Answer (score 3):

It could be:

> The Higgs Boson

**I am a ghost
discarnate and sneaky.
Invisible at most.
Catching me is tricky.**

> The existence of Higgs has been very difficult to confirm

**I am an awkward loner
team work is not my thing at all.
To cooperate with my persona
you need huge meeting hall.**

> The Higgs is a loner because it is an elementary particle. To find it you need a Large Hadron Collider

**I am very fair
and never pick a side.**

> A bit of a stretch, but a team of international scientists work at CERN

**You know me, I am everywhere.**

> The Higgs field is present everywhere

Comment: close, but some details do not fit :)

Answer (score 3):

I might be completely off track, but I believe the answer is

> A photon

The sentences that lead me to this conclusion are:

I am a ghost
discarnate and sneaky.
Invisible at most.
Catching me is tricky.

> A "ghost" as in "can't be perceived when you touch it". Disincarnate because it has "no" mass, hard to catch because studying it has been historically difficult

To cooperate with my persona you need a huge meeting hall

> "a person's perceived or evident personality, as that of a well-known official, actor, or celebrity; personal image; public role." from  [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/persona).In this sense a photon's persona could be the Sun, thus the "huge meeting hall" to cooperate with it

I am very fair

> fair meaning bright

and never pick a side

> the particle-wave duality

Can't figure out the other hints

Comment: I like the part with the particle-wave duality :)